# How to change a live stream during call between peers in PeerJs?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I have a NodeJS application that replicates Zoom. I have figured out on how to stream live audio and video between peers. Now I am stuck at a point where I need to add an option of screen sharing. Please tell me a way to change the stream to "screenStream". Screen sharing has to start when a button with id "shareScreen" is clicked.

Here is the script.js file (By the way I am using PeerJS library for P2P call and connection:

```
var socket = io('/');
var myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: 'peerjs-server.herokuapp.com',
    port: '443',
    secure: true
});

var videoGrid = document.getElementById('videoGrid');
var myVideo = document.createElement('video');
myVideo.muted = true;

var peers = {};

myPeer.on('open', (id) => {
    socket.emit('join-room', roomId, id);

    document.getElementById('disconnectButton').onclick = () => {
        socket.emit('disconnected');
        window.location = "https://www.google.com";
    }
});

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
}).then((stream) => {

    socket.on('user-connected', (userId) => {
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
    });

    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

    myPeer.on('call', (call) => {
        call.answer(stream);
        const videoElement = document.createElement('video');
        call.on('stream', (userVideoStream) => {
            addVideoStream(videoElement, userVideoStream);
        });
    });

    document.getElementById("videoToggler").onclick = () => {
        if (stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled) {
            stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = false;
            stream.getVideoTracks()[0].muted = false;
            document.getElementById("videoToggler").classList.remove('fa-video');
            document.getElementById("videoToggler").classList.add('fa-video-slash');
            document.getElementById("videoToggler").style.color = "#FF0000";
        } else {
            stream.getVideoTracks()[0].enabled = true;
            stream.getVideoTracks()[0].muted = true;
            document.getElementById("videoToggler").classList.remove('fa-video-slash');
            document.getElementById("videoToggler").classList.add('fa-video');
            document.getElementById("videoToggler").style.color = "#000000";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("audioToggler").onclick = () => {
        if (stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled) {
            stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
            stream.getAudioTracks()[0].muted = false;
            document.getElementById("audioToggler").classList.remove('fa-microphone');
            document.getElementById("audioToggler").classList.add('fa-microphone-slash');
            document.getElementById("audioToggler").style.color = "#FF0000";
        } else {
            stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
            stream.getAudioTracks()[0].muted = true;
            document.getElementById("audioToggler").classList.remove('fa-microphone-slash');
            document.getElementById("audioToggler").classList.add('fa-microphone');
            document.getElementById("audioToggler").style.color = "#000000";
        }
    }
});

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
    var call = myPeer.call(userId, stream);
    peers[userId] = call;
    const videoElement = document.createElement('video');
    call.on('stream', (userVideoStream) => {
        addVideoStream(videoElement, userVideoStream);
    });
    call.on('close', () => {
        videoElement.remove();
    });
}

function addVideoStream(videoElement, stream) {
    videoElement.autoplay = true;
    videoElement.srcObject = stream;
    videoGrid.append(videoElement);
}

socket.on('user-disconnected', (userId) => {
    peers[userId].close();
});
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this!?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Nope :(

Comment: I am trying to do it. So far I am able to update the stream from audio video to screen sharing. I will post the answer when I complete my solution

Comment: So does the stream on the web page also change?

Comment: You have to update the video stream with screen sharing stream

Comment: Yes I have tried doing what you said, but the stream gets updated only for me, the other users who have joined previously aren't able to, if a new user joins he can but the previous users couldn't. Could you share a code of what you had done?

Comment: You don't hace to just update the stream you also have to call all yours peers. That will give them your updated stream. Try to dig into peerjs official documentation which has helped me a lot. I will soon post my updated code on GitHub and give you the link.

Comment: Should I close the existing call?